# Insert into table using for loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I am trying to write a loop that will read a staging table and then consequently insert that record into a another table. The reason I need to do single record processing is that I need to find the value of the Sequence after every insert into the target table. I haven't added that functionality to the SQL (that will come later). I am having difficulty inserting the records into the target table.

I am getting a syntax error, but I think there is more that needs to be fixed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_insert()
  RETURNS SETOF varchar AS
$func$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN   
   FOR rec IN
        SELECT * FROM   TBL_stg01
   LOOP INSERT  INTO target_tbl
        SELECT * FROM TBL_stg01
;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Comment: This appears to be interacting with dome kind of database, yet you have neglected to identify which.

Comment: You might want to identify what the syntax error is, if you'd like help in how to fix it.

Comment: No need for a loop or a function: `insert into target_tbl select * from tbl_stg01 returning id`.

Comment: I see an `END IF` statement, but no `IF`; I see a `FOR` statement, but no `END FOR`.

Comment: @ScottHunter: There is no `END FOR`. Only the `LOOP` needs an `END LOOP`. You're right about the `END IF`, though.

Answer (score 1):

#### PL/pgSQL function audited

There are a couple of problems:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_insert()
   RETURNS SETOF varchar AS   -- what do you want to return?
$func$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN   
   FOR rec IN
      SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl_stg01  -- only needed columns
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO target_tbl (col1, col2, col3)
      VALUES (rec.col1, rec.col2, rec.col3)
      -- SELECT (rec).*  -- possible shorthand
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- If `tbl_stg01` and `target_tbl` share the same row type, and you wanted to `INSERT` *all* columns from the source table you *could* work without an explicit target list. But since you obviously have an auto-incremented id, you most probably can't. You shouldn't in any case. Like [Joe already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487737/939860).
  Note how I only select needed columns in the first place.
- You had an `END IF` without starting an `IF` block.
- A function that writes to tables cannot be declared `STABLE`. I removed the keyword, so the default [function volatility `VOLATILE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) kicks in.
- Your function is declared as `RETURNS SETOF varchar` but you are not returning anything ...

#### Proper solution

You mention that you `need to find the value of the Sequence after every insert`, but you fail to provide your table definition, clarify which sequence or what you need it for.

Either way, this is how you return automatically generated default values after an `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO target_tbl (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM   tbl_stg01
RETURNING *
```

Related answer:

- [How to select inside a FOR-Loop for further computations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450490/how-to-select-inside-a-for-loop-for-further-computations/27454370#27454370)

You could chain this with more commands in a single statement with [data-modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) like

```
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO target_tbl (col1, col2, col3)
   SELECT col1, col2, col3
   FROM   tbl_stg01
   RETURNING target_tbl_id
   )
INSERT INTO tbl3 (some_id)
SELECT target_tbl_id
FROM   ins;
```

More examples with explanation:

- [Passing a record as function argument PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716024/passing-a-record-as-function-argument-pl-pgsql/12716275#12716275)
- [Return value cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388076/return-value-cross-join/22392556#22392556)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention your column names specifically in the insert, and you don't need to "reselect" your data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_insert()
  RETURNS SETOF varchar AS
$func$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN   
   FOR rec IN
        SELECT * FROM   TBL_stg01
   LOOP INSERT  INTO target_tbl (colaname1, colname2, colname3...)
        values (rec.col1, rec.col2, rec.col3...);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```